# Having trouble permanently setting gateway

Tags: 12.04, networking

I am on a ubuntu 12.04 vm

I read https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html

which says I can set the gateway with a command like:

> sudo route add default gw 10.0.2.211 eth0

which works, but clears after a reboot.

I also tried to set the gateway by editing my `/etc/network/interface` file:

`auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
gateway 10.0.2.211
pre-up sleep 2`

I just added the gateway line.

That doesn't seem to work at all though.

I tried rebooting and running:

> sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 [dirty]

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

put

```
ifconfig eth0 10.0.2.211 netmask 255.255.255.0 &&
route add default gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

crtl+O [write] and crtl+x [close nano]. And the end of boot process ubuntu read and execute rc.local

Solution 2 [clear]

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
netmask XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

crtl+O [write] and crtl+x [close nano].

Your ip and gw can not be same ip address.
If you wish to set only gateway after dhcp, put only this in rc.local

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local

route add default gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

crtl+O [write] and crtl+x [close nano]

Comment: Ahh.. So is the reason the `/etc/network/interfaces` isn't setting the gateway because I am using **dhcp** and not **static**?

Comment: Yes. Dhcp commpletly configure nic card.